# How to Create Attribute Groups in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Contact Builder using the API

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

Is it possible to create an Attribute Group in Contact Builder, simliar how you can create [Journey Builder Interaction Workflows](http://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/getting-started.html)? I can't find a RESTful method to do this. It would be great if this is possible, and even better if it's similar to [WDF](http://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/reference.html) where Attributes and linked Data Extensions are defined as JSON objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`contacts`](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html#contacts) api which will allow you to get and update schemas and attribute groups.

It doesn't appear as though this functionality to create new ones currently exists, however.

Comment: Thanks Kelly, I'd really appreciate if you could submit this as a feature request as I think others would also benefit from this.

Comment: i think there are efforts to improve the entire contacts api. I chatted with the develope for them, and i think there may be some new great things in the future. Stay tuned!